# I want to show a webpage which will be visible for specific country only

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to show a webpage which will be visible in India only and for the rest of the world it should redirect to another page ,can anybody tell me how I can add this functionality using Drupal 7 ?

Comment: You want to use [this](http://drupal.org/project/geoip) and do something like [this](http://drupal.org/project/geoip_redirect)

Comment: @JonLin Geo IP redirect is a Drupal 6 module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect IP of user and redirect based on that. To detect IPs you can use Drupal Modules like GeoIP, SmartIP etc.. All these modules only provide APIs i.e you need to write your logic in modules/themes. Choose one for which you need least maintanence. For geoIp you need to keep updating County List DAT file manually once in 3~4 months, I am not sure about others. Once you choose your module you have to write logic for your scenario, something like this (This will redirect users only from front page i.e www.example.com, if you want you can add this to `hook_init()` so that its checked in all pages.

```
$cc = geoip_country_code();
if($cc == "IN"){
  drupal_goto(MY_INDIAN_SITE_URL);
}
else{
  drupal_goto(REST_OF_WORLD_PAGE);
}
```

You can use [page--front.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) or make use of [drupal_is_front_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) in page.tpl.php to write your own logic.